# javascript on ipad while scrolling doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

It seems as javascript:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000);
})
```

never fires while scrolling on the iPad/safari. Is there any workaround for this?

(on android stock browser ok)

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy as it seems. When I was need functionality like that, I began to use the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) library with small changes in the source.

I've used it with the CSS provided in the "ios-perfect-scrollbar" example, and onScrollMove event. But to fire this event even on "momentum scrolling", you'll need to add

`if (that.options.onScrollMove) that.options.onScrollMove.call(that, e);`

at the end of "animate" function.